# Can I say "The country's ongoing widely discussed problems are hopeless"

Tags: sentence-construction, adverbs, nouns, adjective-phrases, compounds

Can I use the combination of "adjective + adverb + adjective + noun" like

> The country's ongoing widely discussed problems are hopeless.
> (Or instead do I need to say ongoing widely-discussed problems)

> It is an expensive well-designed program. (Or instead do I need to say a well-designed expensive program)

Answer (score 1):

> The country's ongoing widely discussed problems are hopeless.

> The country's ongoing widely-discussed problems are hopeless.

> It is an expensive well-designed program.

> It is a well-designed expensive program.

We need a hyphen after *widely* to form the adjective *widely-discussed*.

The terms *ongoing* and *widely-discussed* are coordinate adjectives, and we should have commas to separate them.  As for the order, I feel having the former first sounds more natural.

Similarly, *expensive* and *well-designed* are coordinate adjectives; I feel *expensive, well-designed* sounds better than the reverse.  I suggest

> The country's *ongoing, widely-discussed* problems are hopeless.

> It is an *expensive, well-designed* program.